# Sd card gets corrupted on some monitors?

Tags: sd-card, kernel, noobs, corrupt

When connected to Monitor **DELL e2218hn**, SD card with NOOBS installed is getting corrupted within 2-3 hours of use. This is not the case with other monitors as it works really smooth.

**ISSUE:**

When Pi is working ok for 2-3 hours, it gets blank all of a sudden. When we restart it, it shows following error.

> end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on
>   unknown-block(179,7)

Then I search on google with above error. They suggested to make SD card "Read-Only". So to further solve this issue, I made SD card as Read-Only. Still then the problem exist. It's just I don't have to reprogram SD card but to restart it.

Am confused, as output is received by monitor and not PI, how can it corrupt SD card that way?

Is this resolution issue? Can Raspberry Pi work with Full-HD monitor?

If yes, then why is it not working with this particular model? If no, then what resolution raspberry pi work with?

Comment: In what way is your SD card being corrupted? Using a full HD monitor shouldn't cause an issue pi's are certainly capable of displaying a full HD image. Please describe exactly what is happening when you are using the monitor. Plugging the pi into a monitor is highly unlikely to affect the sd card in any way.

Comment: Question updated, it's showing error about kernel panic

Comment: In configuration setting, its showing resolution options only upto 1440. https://prnt.sc/mn86ry